# Find Class file name that Refer class inside JAR

Tags: java

I would like to write java program that will print Class file name that Refer class inside JAR like below,

My jar file name : ExportExcel.jar it has class `com/example/ExportXLSXExcel.class`

below is my Java class that refer above class

```
import com.example.*;

Class DisputeProcess {
ExportXLSXExcel excel = new ExportXLSXExcel();
excel.download();
}
```

When I provide jar file name `ExportExcel.jar`. Java program should print `DisputeProcess`. Because `DisputeProcess` referred a class that inside `ExportExcel.jar`

Comment: jdeps has similar facility. I can't remember if it has listings on individual classes though.

Comment: What is your issue exactly, you have told us what you want to do but not what is stopping you from doing it?